# Terraform - Loop over a folder to create n indivual ressources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a folder `queries` where a user will add, delete and modify `yaml` files. Each yaml file represent a single terraform resource on GCP, a **Scheduling Query**.

What would be the cleanest way to loop over the queries folder and to generate the appropriate number of terraform resource in main `main.tf` accordingly? I can use Python to generate the `main.tf` if it is easier

Example for 1 signel ressource:

**queries/alpha.yaml**

```
display_name: "my-query"
data_source_id: "scheduled_query"
schedule: "first sunday of quarter 00:00"
destination_dataset_id: "results"
destination_table_name_template: "my_table"
write_disposition: "WRITE_APPEND"
query: "SELECT name FROM tabl WHERE x = 'y'"
```

This should create this ressource in my **main.tf**

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
  display_name           = "my-query"
  data_source_id         = "scheduled_query"
  schedule               = "first sunday of quarter 00:00"
  destination_dataset_id = "results"
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = "my_table"
    write_disposition               = "WRITE_APPEND"
    query                           = "SELECT name FROM tabl WHERE x = 'y'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, I used your code, it worked well. I forgot to accept your anwser, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read all the files in your `locals`:

```
locals {
  
   query_files = fileset(path.module, "queries/*.yaml")
   
   queries = {for query_file in local.query_files: 
              query_file => yamldecode(file(query_file))}
}
```

then use `for_each` to create your resource:

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {

  for_each               = local.queries

  display_name           = each.value.display_name
  data_source_id         = each.value.data_source_id
  schedule               = each.value.schedule
  destination_dataset_id = each.value.destination_dataset_id
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = each.value.destination_table_name_template
    write_disposition               = each.value.write_disposition
    query                           = each.value.query
  }
}
```